# How to get this done in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select

Consider i have a registartion table and there is field `prefLocationId` and it contains value like this `1,2,3`,`2`,`1,4` and so many.... And i have a table `prefLocation` which looks like this

```
Id LocationName
1  Chennai
2  Mumbai
3  Kolkatta
4  Delhi
```

and i want to select record of users and show values like

`Chennai,Mumbai,Kolkatta`,`Mumbai`,`Chennai,Delhi` and so on...

Comment: There are ways to do it, but all of them are rather complicated. The right solution would be to properly normalize your data, and store those `prefLocationId` values in a separate table (one value per row). That would make the query trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be table prefLocationId, not field
and then you can select something like

```
SELECT pref.*,group_concat(prefLocation.name) 
FROM pref, prefLocationId, prefLocation 
WHERE pref.LocationId=prefLocationId.pref and prefLocation.id=prefLocationId.location
GROUP BY pref.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I almost don't want to do this but there is an answer.  Only, its about the worst possible thing I could imagine doing.  You should really consider Col. Shrapnel's answer and split your values off into a separate table.  But for the sake of completeness:

```
  SELECT registration.*, GROUP_CONCAT(prefLocation.name) AS prefLocationNames
    FROM registration
    JOIN prefLocation ON FIND_IN_SET(prefLocation.Id, registration.prefLocationId) > 0
GROUP BY registration.id
```

This will be VERY slow in comparison to what you would get if you split `registration.prefLocationId` because there's absolutely no way for this to use any indexes.